# MathJax doesn't display in the new profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, profile-page

This seems suboptimal:

[image: a list of posts, some of which should have MathJax rendered and don't]

I'm running Mac OS 10.10.3. This happens for me in Safari (8.0.5), Firefox (38.0) and Chrome (41.0.2272.118), although in Chrome I do get a brief flash of equations during rendering.

Comment: I have the same problem on my profile page.

Comment: I have the same thing with Firefox 38.0 on Windows 7

Comment: Same here, on Chrome latest and Comodo Dragon (Chrome clone) on Windows 7.

Comment: I suggest adding this to the [bugs and feedback master list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253450#tab-top)

Comment: I added it there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253499 (plus another, maybe related bug).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the new styles on the page caused the rendered MathJax to be rendered in the incorrect position (and also hid it).

You could see that as a flicker of the page, seeing the rendered MathJax (in the wrong position), which then suddenly disappeared.

I also added the missing re-rendering when changing the sorting & filtering.